# Select column names in a table using PyODBC

Tags: python, ms-access, ms-access-2007, pyodbc

I'm writing a Python program that selects some data from a Microsoft Access mdb file using PyODBC.

I need to discover the column names of several different tables. In SQL Server, this can be accomplished by using a query like

```
SELECT c.name FROM sys.columns c, sys.tables t
WHERE c.object_id = t.object_id
AND t.name = tableName
```

But that query doesn't work in Access. With

```
SELECT MSysObjects.Name FROM MSysObjects
WHERE (((MSysObjects.Flags)=0) AND ((MSysObjects.Type)=1))
ORDER BY MSysObjects.Name
```

I can get a list of non-linked table names, but MSysObject doesn't seem to contain a list of column names.

Is there a way to use SQL to grab the column names of a table in an Access database?

Comment: If you have a connection, can you use an ADO Schema: `Set rs = cn.OpenSchema(adSchemaTables, Array(Empty, Empty, Empty, "tablenamehere"))` ? See also http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kcax58fh(VS.80).aspx

Comment: I cannot. But while I was looking that up, I discovered that PyODBC has a helper method that uses SQLColumns.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was unable to find an SQL query to accomplish this. However, I did discover that PyODB has a cursor method that can return a list of columns

```
# columns in table x
for row in cursor.columns(table='x'):
    print row.column_name
```

Comment: I found that in old .mdb files that it was the fourth element i.e. row[3] that is the actual name of the column.

Comment: I have an old mdb(1995) and i can't get column names.not even with row[3].

Answer (score 1):

Python 3

To access by conlumn name

```
table_row = conn.execute(query)
for row in table_rows:
     print (row.nameColumn)
```

To access by conlumn index

```
table_row = conn.execute(query)
for row in table_rows:
     print (row[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the limitations in querying that version of MS-Access, but a solution I've seen used in other similar situations is to SELECT * FROM table LIMIT = 0 (or 1 depending). You are then able to gather the returned column names from the result.

Comment: Access doesn't support LIMIT; nor does it seem to like "SELECT TOP 0 * FROM table" http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208930%28office.12%29.aspx

Comment: "WHERE 1=2" will return zero rows.

Comment: Selecting zero rows gives me "None".

Comment: Gives you "None" in what context? A recordset with zero rows still has a complete fields collection, so maybe your probleml has to do with how you're executing the SELECT.

Comment: cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM table WHERE 1=2"); print cursor.fetchone() #Returns "None". Anyway, the cursor.columns function looks like the preferred way to go about this.