# pyodbc Access database MSysObjects permissions issue

Tags: python, ms-access, pyodbc

I'm trying to access an Access database (`.mdb`) using `pyodbc`.

I can connect to it fine—

```
connection = pyodbc.connect(driver='{Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}', dbp=path, pwd=password)
```

But I can't query `MSysObjects` to get a list of its tables—

```
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute('select * from MSysObjects where Type=1 and Flags=0')
```

It gives me—

```
Record(s) cannot be read; no read permission on 'MSysObjects'. (-1907) (SQLExecDirectW)
```

Browsing around, it appears to be because the database has been "protected".

I can't run Access to change it. Is there anywhere I can resolve this programatically? Will I need to know the database users or something like that?

[I've seen a workaround in Visual Basic](http://forums.asp.net/post/1240015.aspx)—is there a way I could adapt that in Python? I'd guess I'd need a different library (OLEDB).

Thanks!

Comment: Can you not get the schema from the connection? The Access system tables are unsupported and really not suitable for this.

Comment: Perhaps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4539254/how-to-get-datatypes-of-specific-fields-of-an-access-database-using-pyodbc

Comment: Thanks @Remou—that looks very useful. I'm looking into it now

Comment: Ha, I would never have thought it were that easy—`cursor.tables()` works like a charm. Write it up, @Remou—you deserve the upvotes :-)

Answer (score 6):

The solution is to use `cursor.tables()` as demonstrated in the code-snippet below:

```
import pyodbc
connection = pyodbc.connect(driver='{Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}', dbp=path, pwd=password)
cursor = connection.cursor()
tableNames = [x[2] for x in cursor.tables().fetchall() if x[3] == 'TABLE']
```

There's probably a cleaner way of coding this, but I'm in a hurry ;)

(credit goes to those that commented to the original question; I just posted this code because I'm writing it into my notes anyway)

Answer (score 0):

I realize I'm coming in late, but I recently had this same issue and thought I'd share the function I wrote for getting table/column schema.

```
def get_schema(cursor):
    """
    :param cursor: Cursor object to database
    :return: Dictionary with table name as key and list of columns as value
    """
    db_schema = dict()
    tbls = cursor.tables().fetchall()

    for tbl in tbls:
        if tbl not in db_schema:
            db_schema[tbl] = list() #  add table as key

        column_names = list()
        for col in cursor.columns(table=tbl):  # concatenate column names
            column_names.append(col[3])

        db_schema[tbl] = tuple(column_names)  # store column names as value
    return dict(db_schema)
```

The idea is you could later append data tuples to the list which has the column names:

```
{'Table 1': [('Column 1-1', 'Column 1-2')],
 'Table 2': [('Column 2-1', 'Column 2-2', 'Column 2-3')]}
```