# Receiving quantity and list of fields of the table

Tags: python, sql, database, ms-access, pyodbc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get datatypes of specific fields of an Access database using pyodbc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4539254/how-to-get-datatypes-of-specific-fields-of-an-access-database-using-pyodbc)

What sql request receives quantity of fields of the table Access in pyodbc connection with database? What sql request receives the list of fields of the table Access in pyodbc connection with database?

Comment: You only need to query the list of fields. The size of the returned list will answer the first question.

Answer (score 3):

You can get both the number of columns in your table and the names of those columns using pyodbc's [cursor.columns](http://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/wiki/Cursor#columns) method.

```
import pyodbc
db_path = r'C:\Users\hans\Documents\sample.mdb'
cnnct_strng = 'DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ=%s' % db_path
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(cnnct_strng)
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
print 'Columns: %i' % (len(cursor.columns(table='YourTable').fetchall()))
for row in cursor.columns(table='YourTable'):
    print row.column_name
cursor.close()
cnxn.close()
```